# Swift Codable: Array of Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, codable

I have a JSON object from Yelp and I cannot figure out how to access the `title` in `categories` using Swift Codable. This is the JSON (with some elements removed for ease of reading):

```
{
    "businesses": [
        {
        "id": "fob-poke-bar-seattle-2",
        "name": "FOB Poke Bar",
        "is_closed": false,
        "review_count": 421,
        "categories": [
            {
                "alias": "poke",
                "title": "Poke"
            },
            {
                "alias": "salad",
                "title": "Salad"
            },
            {
                "alias": "hawaiian",
                "title": "Hawaiian"
            }
        ],
        "rating": 5,
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 47.6138005187095,
            "longitude": -122.343868017197
        },
        "price": "$$",
        "location": {
            "city": "Seattle",
            "zip_code": "98121",
            "country": "US",
            "state": "WA",
            "display_address": [
                "220 Blanchard St",
                "Seattle, WA 98121"
            ]
        },
    }
```

[Here it is in JSON Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAs7.png)

I access first level properties like `name` easily, and I access `lattitude` and `longitude` like so:

```
class Business: Codable {

  var name: String
  var rating: Double
  var coordinates: Coordinates

  struct Coordinates: Codable {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(lat: Double, long: Double) {
      self.latitude = lat
      self.longitude = long
    }
  }

  init(name: String, rating: Double, coordinates: Coordinates) {
    self.name = name
    self.rating = rating
    self.coordinates = coordinates
    self.categories = categories
  }
}
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction towards accessing `categories` -> `title`? `Coordinates` was easy to access but `categories` is an **array of dictionaries.** Thank you!

Comment: You may just declare new codable type, like you did with `Coordinates` and declare property `categories: Category` in `Business` type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same pattern like `Coordinates` except the value for `categories` is an array:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let businesses : [Business]
}

struct Business: Decodable {

    let name: String
    let rating: Int
    let coordinates: Coordinates

    let categories : [Category]

    struct Coordinates: Codable {
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
    }

    struct Category: Codable {
        let alias: String
        let title: String
    }
}
```

---

```
let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
for business in root.businesses {
        for category in business.categories {
            print(category.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to parse if "businesses" is not available in the at the beginning of json. Its just array of dictionaries I my case.

Comment: The decode the array, in the given example `try decoder.decode([Business].self, from: data)`

Comment: @vadian is there a way to parse this without taking a new struct as Root with the above json

Comment: Basically yes, but you have to implement `init(from decoder` and what is the benefit of writing a dozen lines of code?

Comment: @vadian I tried, But I think its not possible to parse array coming in a dictionary as a root. Can you throw some light on the init function as I am only able to get the container as `let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)`. What will be the next step? Only thing is to avoid making a new Struct as Root. For sure the loc will be more but the model will be standalone and not dependent on `Root` or any other struct

Comment: You have to parse the array as `nestedUnkeyedContainer`. But once again in terms of efficiency the synthesized way with extra root struct is preferable.

Comment: @vadian by writing `try decoder.decode([Business].self, from: data)` and writing in init after the container line `let businesses = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: . businesses)` and also defining in `CodingKeys` enum. But where to allocate the unkeyedContainer? You are correct about the efficiency but, currently the only objective is to avoid the `Root` struct.

Comment: I take my statement back. It's not possible to decode the array directly. But what's wrong to proceed with `root.businesses`?

Comment: @vadian So, we can say that if the JSON is something like this, you need a temporary `Root` or `Response` struct/class  in case of Codable. But except Codable, (basically using our old JSONSerialization), we don't need any `Root` or something. Disadvantage or limitation of Codable? Your answer is perfectly fine. Just playing with Codable and trying to understand how it is better than others. I prefer other libs like swiftyJSON or so which are really handly and provide filtered content. Though some lines of code are there.

Comment: You **do** need *any `Root` or something* with `JSONSerialization` (and `SwiftyJSON`) because you have to cast the root object to `[String:Any]` and get the array for key `businesses`. In fact that's the same `Codable` does

Comment: @vadian, but that can be temporary/local dictionary without having to create a struct or so for the same. Exact landing to the source what we need.

Comment: This is not an argument. You can create the struct in another struct or class which gets deallocated after parsing the data.

Comment: @vadian also in case of json where in a dictionary of an array if we have lots and lots of nested dictionary and we just want the key to be associated with our main model, Codable required init decoder method, then the containers, nested containers etc whereas we can just land to exact key value using SwiftyJSON, for instance `response["businesses"].arrayValue[0]["a"]["b"]["c"].stringValue` something like that.
Hmm, BTW I am fine with your answer but I generally prefer other libs if the json is so nested.

Comment: Using the appropriate structs your example translated to `Decodable` is `response.businesses.first!.a.b.c` which is much more efficient because the type of `businesses` and `c` is well-known and the other values are type safe.